# Open Selection in Microsoft Excel and Publish back to the server from ASP.NET Web Form Application. No SharePoint on the server

Tags: asp.net, forms, excel, sharepoint, web

On ASP.NET Web Forms, is it possible to open selected rows in Excel, modify data and publish changes back to the server (similar to Visual Studio TFS)?   What technologies are available for this?  Unfortunately I cannot use SharePoint for this.

Comment: So the idea would be that you would download a copy of a spreadsheet, modify the data, and post the modified spreadsheet back, where it would take the place of the previous spreadsheet?